Strategy for floating floor in a weird space?
My upstairs hallway is... Complicated. Due to the house's history, it is on two different levels, and has space carved out of it for chimney, built-in bookcases, corner of a bathtub, and a closet.
It also has a fairly hideous and worn out carpet that I'd like to get rid of. Unfortunately, what's under the carpet is vinyl tiles, quite likely containing asbestos, so something else will have to be put down to re-encapsulate those.
Floating floor would be the obvious solution. But in such a convoluted space, I'm not sure where to start from.
My instincts say run most of the boards in the same direction as the existing floorboards, to minimize calling attention to the difference, and just kludge thresholds as best I can. But I wanted to do a fast sanity check as to whether there is a best, or at least better, practice for handling this sort of space to minimize trial-and-error.
("You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all different...")



*Update:" It turns out that the lower section of the hallway is just carpet over padding over subfloor. However, I have confirmed that the upper section is the same tiles as in the adjacent bathroom; photo above. I'm still walking on that, so I could consider just exposing the tile. But it's not exactly pretty, so I am still thinking about the floating floor. (Greenish tile under salmon wall? Though repainting is easier than flooring, and the tile seems to work ok with the bathrooms lilac.)
Junction between carpet and bathroom floor for comparison: 

If you need an excuse to get a table saw and a mitre saw, this is it.  If just the first space, I would turn the boards the opposite way, but if going past, then I do not think it matters.

Have table saw; don't have miter saw. Yet?

Oh I see a trip to the toy store in your future.  Pick up a couple of fine tooth blades also.

Correct measurements will be very important.  Maybe one of those shape copiers for the doorways, or a saw to cut the bottoms.  Lay out as much of the flooring first before cutting, so you do not cut the wrong end off.  Learnt that lesson the hard way.

@crip659: That may be starting to add up to an Answer...?

In my (admittedly limited) experience, the asbestos tile was typically used on a solid (concrete) substrate.  Hopefully you have some luck.  How do you know that the flooring at the bottom of your top pic doesn't continue under the carpet?

@Huesmann: Thanks for asking! It turns out that the lower corridor appears to be just carpet over subfloor. The newer section however appears to be the same tile as in the bathroom. Photo added. I am guessing mid-1960s.

Wait, there's bathroom tile under the carpet?

Apparently, they just told the whole section of raised floor when they put in the bathroom, then later put a carpet over that tile. Or at least that's what it looks like; I'll post a picture of the bathroom tile too for comparison. If you think of it as vinyl flooring rather than specifically bathroom tile, it makes a sort of sense in terms of efficiency...

Given how often my cat deposits hairballs in this hallway, I might almost be willing to tolerate the tile. But I definitely want some hard surface, rather than the carpet.

Lay out as much as the flooring as possible in one direction first.  Give it a couple of days to just look at it. Change to the other direction and repeat.  This is long term(5 to twenty years or more) flooring, so getting it right is important.  Some people are picky about direction.
Cutting measurements are very important.  Measure twice and cut once, and repeat is good saying to go by.
Doorways can get fancy with shape copiers/coping saws or use an oscillating saw to cut door moulding just above flooring.
You will want fine tooth blades for a table and/or a mitre saw(reason to go to toy store for one or both).
Make sure you cut the right end off.  Most of those planks have grooves/tongues on all four sides.  Do not repeat my mistakes.
Make sure your S.O. agrees with your choices(or get her choice).
Except for the cuts you have it easy.  I choose to start at a straight empty wall and work towards the fridge/stove/dryer/washer.  Next time I start moving heavy stuff first.
You want to leave about 1/4 inch at the edges, covered by baseboard.  Read instructions first.
